# Input formula into cell using xlR1C1 style

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula to implement in xlR1C1 style.

I add a new marketing entry into my marketing database. I want `Cells (emptyRowM,9)` to search a marketing referral code in `Cells (emptyRowM, 7)` in the pivot table of another sheet. This pivot table shows the total revenue associated to each marketing referral code. Hence if `Cells (emptyRowM, 7)` is zero, `Cells (emptyRowM, 9` will be blank, otherwise, it will sum up all the revenue associated with the referral code.

```
Dim emptyRowM As Long
emptyRowM = Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 
Cells (emptyRowM, 9) = "=IF(AND(SUMIF('Pivot Table'!B6:B99,'Marketing Data'!G12,'Pivot Table'!C6:C99)=0),"",SUMIF('Pivot Table'!B6:B99,'Marketing Data'!G12,'Pivot Table'!C6:C99))"
```

Comment: Cells (emptyRowM, 9).Formula =...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go File-> Options -> Formulas there under working with Formula tick "R1C1 reference style"

So your formula should become something like

=IF(AND(SUMIF('Pivot Table'!R[-5]C[-5]:R[88]C[-5],'Marketing Data'!R[1]C,'Pivot Table'!R[-5]C[-4]:R[88]C[-4])=0),"",SUMIF('Pivot Table'!R[-5]C[-5]:R[88]C[-5],'Marketing Data'!

Then use the Cells (emptyRowM, 9).FormulaR1C1="=IF(AND(SUMIF('Pivot Table'!R[-5]C[-5]:R[88]C[-5],'Marketing Data'!R[1]C,'Pivot Table'!R[-5]C[-4]:R[88]C[-4])=0),"",SUMIF('Pivot Table'!R[-5]C[-5]:R[88]C[-5],'Marketing Data'!"

Let me know if you have any problems.

Cheers,
Sujoy

Comment: Works perfectly! Just need to put double quotation marks in the vba code and it will be good! Thanks!